# Count the number of intervals that fall in the given range

Tags: algorithm, tree, language-agnostic, range, intervals

Suppose you have a list of intervals, such as [(0 4), (1 3), (2 5), (2 6)]. This list is not sorted. Then you are given a range, such as [1 5]. You have to return the number of intervals that fit inside of the range. In this problem, it would return 2. ((1 3) and (2 5))

The list of intervals stays constant, but we are given at most 100000 queries, which each consists of a range. For every range query we have to return the number of intervals that fit inside.

After researching I read about [Interval Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). However, you can only query for intervals that **overlap** with any given range, while I'm looking for intervals that **fall within** the range. These queries take logarithmic time.

Is there any way to solve this problem in a similar time complexity, possibly with a variation of interval trees? I'm not looking for a linear solution (as brute force would anyway mean scanning through all the intervals).

Comment: Are you getting multiple queries for the same list of intervals?

Comment: Yes, at most 10^5.

Comment: Easy if you get all the queries at the same time. Otherwise pretty hard.  You're leaving out a lot of details in the question, so....

Comment: Yes, you get the queries at the same time - I'll add it to my post.

Comment: If there are any other details you need I'll add it :)

Comment: Your explanation of the problem is not very clear. Let me restate it: You are given a bunch of ranges (100000?), and don't care how much it takes to preprocess them. All you care is that when you are given another range, you can find the number of ranges that completely contain it with a minimal time complexity. Is this correct?

Comment: I edited my post @WalterTross. The list of intervals stays constant, but we are given at most 100000 queries, which each consists of a range. For every range query we have to return the number of intervals that fit inside.

Comment: Ok, so the 100000 is not the max number of ranges to check against, but the max number of test ranges. Apart from this, is my rendition of the problem correct or not?

Comment: Please find the detailed answer on this [stackoverflow-link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64137/how-many-range-are-completely-inside-a-given-range) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Adding assumptions that this segments aren't that long if you will add an interval you can remember id in the node of the tree and you will need to remember just segments crossing points *a* and *b*, so you will just ask segment tree to get vector of id's crossing a and b. And from a different tree, you will ask about the number of endings in segment a-b. After you will just remove id which occurred once. It should be faster.